# Gogle search python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to make a program: after entering keywords, the program will automatically enter google and return results as shown.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDQCR.png)

this is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def query():
    user_query = input('Enter your query: ')

    URL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" + user_query

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36 Edg/89.0.774.57'
    }

    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    result = soup.find(class_='Uo8X3b OhScic zsYMMe').get_text()
    print(result)


while True:
    try:
        query()
    except Exception:
        print('Sorry no result, please be clear')
    user_input = input('To continue press y: ')
    if user_input != 'y':
        break
```

My program is not showing any results
Thanks for help

Comment: Does google automatically change the name of the class?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `soup.find` is filtering the wrong element class.
[image: Google Search HTML Elements]

Start from it's parent class and get the first span element instead.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = '''
<div jscontroller="GCSbhd" jsaction="SKAaMe:c0XUbe;rcuQ6b:npT2md">
  <div jscontroller="GCSbhd" class="kno-rdesc" jsaction="seM7Qe:c0XUbe;Iigoee:c0XUbe;rcuQ6b:npT2md">
    <h3 class="Uo8X3b OhScic zsYMMe">Description</h3>
    <span>Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro GOIH ComM is a Portuguese professional footballer who plays as a forward for Premier League club Manchester United and captains the Portugal national team.</span>
    <span>
      <span></span>
      <a class="ruhjFe NJLBac fl" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristiano_Ronaldo" data-ved="2ahUKEwiwl4qG3q72AhUPhlYBHdJvDvYQmhN6BAhFEAI" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristiano_Ronaldo&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiwl4qG3q72AhUPhlYBHdJvDvYQmhN6BAhFEAI">Wikipedia</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup,"html.parser")
result_element = soup.find('div', class_='kno-rdesc').find('span')

print(result_element.get_text())
```

Result:

```sh
$ python main.py 
Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro GOIH ComM is a Portuguese professional footballer who plays as a forward for Premier League club Manchester United and captains the Portugal national team.
```

**Note**: Google Team might have different class names in different servers or change it over time. You may want to use more filters if you managed to acquire them.